# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

when I run my code, `price.value` says I can't do it like that, but it was done before.
and I get a mistake like this.

> *Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.*

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">price</label>
    <input #price type="text" class="form-control" name="price" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input
        #isactive
        type="checkbox"
        class="custom-control-input"
        id="isActive"
      />
      <label for="" class="custom-control-label" for="isActive"></label>
    </div>
```

**what do I have to do to get the values in the input form. my Button codes are defined below.**

```
 <button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    (click)="
      addProduct(name.value, price.value, isactive.checked);
      name.value = '';
      price.value = '';
      isactive.checked = false
    "
  >
```

I get an error like this and use version angular 11. as far as I can remember, it was working on version 9.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLZBo.png)

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'number'.
>
> ```
> addProduct(name.value, **price.value**, isactive.checked);*>
> ```

**my addProduct function is here**

```
 addProduct(name: string, price: number, isactive: boolean) {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(price);
    console.log(isactive);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Value of an input field is by default a string. So you have to cast it before you put it into your function with

```
addProduct(name.value, parseInt(price.value), isactive.checked)
```

Comment: thank you, but it's still not working. the html side says parseInt is not defined. Property 'parseInt' does not exist on type 'ProductFormComponent'.

Comment: yeah sorry thought you were in standard javascript. You will have to use parseInt in your addProduct function

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of parameter `price` to string. Then inside the function use `parseInt` or `Number` to convert the string to number.

```
addProduct(name: string, price: string, isactive: boolean) {
    const pr = parseInt(price,10);
    if(!isNaN(pr){
       // rest of code her
     }
}
```

If you call the function like this `addProduct(name.value, parseInt(price.value), isactive.checked)` and if `parseInt(price.value)` is not a number, the function will throw an error as `addProduct` is expecting `price.value` to be a number.

For example if price.value is string like 'testString' then `parseInt(testString)` will be `NaN`

Comment: Thank you. I did what they said, I defined it as parseint, but I didn't need to make parseInt on the html side. it was enough for me to define the function as parseInt. Now , it works

Comment: parseInt is a js in built function.

Comment: when you define it in the button class, the angular html side does not see it. it worked when using parseInt in the function

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```html
<!-- bad code -->
<input #price type="text" class="form-control" name="price" />
<!-- good code -->
<input #price type="number" class="form-control" name="price" />
```

Change the input type to number.